# Synchronize users between applications oauth

Tags: java, json, rest

Good afternoon, I have a doubt, will be days I'm trying to get a result but without success. I wish someone would give me a light, I'm able to make the request to synchronize a group of users that is the case (3) to the authentication server which returns me status = 200, which is something that tells me that is working, but in response the return that comes to me is void, and should return users in this way for example:

Ex:  `{"tpUsuario":"admin","messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],"name":"usuario"}`

Here is the method that I did:

```
@XmlElement
public void sincronizarUsuarios() {
        Autenticacao groupThree = new Autenticacao();

        groupThree.setIdGroup(3);

        // The Config.REST_SERVICE_SYNC is my webService;
        Response response = restFactory.getInvocationBuilder(Config.REST_SERVICE_SYNC).post(Entity.json(groupThree));

        // Returns the status of my post and is returning me 200, 
        // This means that making requizição ie is working
        System.out.println(response.getStatus());

       // This should return me the Users in String format but 
       // Return null;
        System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
```

PS: Grammar by Google translator, in Brazil could not help.

Comment: Hard to help. I have no idea what is the REST service you use. Have you tried to use this service manually via some REST console (or browser plugin)? Does it return correct data?

Comment: So I already got the return of a user passing the id of him, but now I'm trying with a group of users and is coming null.

Comment: someone to help?                                  . .

Comment: My comment is still valid - have you tried to run it with group of users in some rest console? It may be good to contact service provider for help.